# Microsoft Project 2013 stops updating dependent dates for single user

Tags: microsoft-project

I have one user who has projects with tasks that are dependent on previous tasks. When he changes a previous task date by a day, Project is supposed to change the following dependent tasks dates, but does not. Other Project 2013 installs work as expected with the same files. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing on this computer with no luck. I have to assume he has some setting in his profile that we're just not aware of, and google just brings up a post on experts exchange which I don't particularly want to pay for to see if it's the answer. So - any experts know what config might be User Profile specific but doesn't follow the Project file?

This is on Windows 7 x64 SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have 'the' answer for you based on the question. Here are some things I would check or try. These things are not that uncommon and it's a bit fiddly to fix.

- Auto Calc - File > Options > Schedule - Usually this is checked. There are good reasons to uncheck / turn it off of course. May seem obvious but I overlook it all the time.
- Scheduling Messages - File > Options > Schedule - Often these get turned off, turning them back on could reveal a message that is relevant to the problem.
- Advice from Planning Wizard - File > Options > Advanced - same train of thought as for the Scheduling messages
- .NET Framework - If this is not current MS Project gets cranky. The latest .NEt is 4.6 I assume MS Project itself is patched up current too.
- I have seen issues if say MS Project was installed and then Office or an Office program was installed after. I try to install & update MS Project after Office and then update .NET
- Sometimes the task just gets corrupt and it has to be recreated, and re-linked. I will typically create a new task, copy/paste the critical info out of the old one, like predecessors & successors, and actual dates, then delete the old one. Copying the entire task usually just moves the problem to the new task. Yes, I have seen these things happen for one user and not the other.
- If it starts cropping up on other tasks or other machines, then I usually export the schedule to .XML, close project, re-open and then open the .XML file as a new project. This has the effect of purging the data base of anything Project doesn't like for lack of a more technical explanation. Oh, then save this new project as an .mpp with the appropriate name, of course.

Hope that helps.

-j

Comment: It was the Auto Calc - one file had it off, turning it on seemed to fix it for other files that were "broken" even though those files showed it "on".

Comment: Cool! Glad that was it. Thanks for the feedback too!